# My PHP App won't display in localhost (only the folders will). I'm using MAMP - app is held in standard htdocs folder

Tags: php, localhost, mamp, htdocs

So I've pulled a repository from github into my htdocs folder.  But when i go to the http://localhost, all I get is a list of the folders in the App (vs seeing the app display in the browser).

i.e, my app is displaying a bulleted list as seen below.  Usually i can get php pages up and running if they have a simple page right in the htdocs directory (index.php, etc).  but this app is more sophisticated & doesn't have that.

I'm a beginner, so i'm sure this is something small I'm overlooking...but some help would be much appreciated.

Index of /
 -App
 -Config
 -Core
 -etc
 -etc
 -etc

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly is that app, could we get a link to the git?

Comment: Charlie, unfortunately its a private repo (& not mine) otherwise i would've.

Answer (score 0):

Something has to pass control to an "index.php" or some other controller that will handle the request and spit out the html you want to see. If the app is supposed to do something, you can try maybe checking the .htaccess file to see what it's supposed to be forwarding to. If all is set up correctly and still not working, then maybe the master httpd.conf has something like AllowOverride None that is preventing the rules/directives/etc in the htaccess from executing correctly

Comment: Hey Adrian, my httpd.conf file in Apache folder does have the following in <Directory "Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin">AllowOverride None | Options None | Order allow, deny | Allow from all</Directory>.  Should i remove all these?

Comment: The one that you would be looking for is a <Directory> that points to your htdocs folder. For example, I set up one for me like this:  <Directory "/Users/me/code/aptana-studio-3-workspace/myproject">
  Inside of that I have     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all